# htaccess redirect rules md5 and keep md5

Tags: regex, .htaccess, rules

I have :

`https://old.example.com/{md5}` I would like transferred to a new domain only if it is an md5 and keep this md5 as a get variable = `https://new.example.com/login?md5={md5}`

I have the following rule

```
    RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ https://new.example.com/login$1 [R=301,L]
```

it works half, it redirects well if the chain is on md5 but does not keep the value of md5. I think it is missing `(.*)`.

I have to keep all the other page which don't have md5

```
https://new.example.com/contact.html
https://new.example.com/bablac/blibli.html
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ https://new.example.com/login$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

**UPDATE:** You are not actually capturing anything, so the `$1` backreference is always empty. You need to either create a capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. surround in parentheses) or use the `$0` backrefernce, which contains the entire match.

You are also redirecting to `/login{md5}`, whereas you stated that you needed to redirect to `/login?md5={md5}` (to "keep this md5 as a get variable"), so you would need to adjust the last part of the rule to read `/login?md5=$1`. In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ https://new.example.com/login?md5=$0 [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache, since the 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser.

I assume that the old and new domains point to different servers, otherwise, you may need a condition that explicitly checks the requested hostname. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ https://new.example.com/login?md5=$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I use wget for test. I have fix witch  RewriteRule "^([a-f0-9]{32})$" ()

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, missed that! I've updated my answer. You can instead just use the `$0` backreference (to match the entire pattern) without modifying the regex.